# Labels and arrows problem in tikz-cd

Tags: tikz-cd

i have a problem with tikz-cd package and a label over an arrow

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=tiny]
&\mathbb{S}ig^I\arrow[dl,phantom , shift left]\arrow[dl, "\left(Mod^{I}\right)^{op}" above, shift right] \arrow[dr, "Sen^{I}"] &\\
\mathbb{C}at^{op}&\models &\mathbb{S}et
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Here is the problem (in the left arrow is the problem)
[image]
Thanks for the help.

Comment: `\arrow[dl, "(Mod^{I})^{op}", swap]`

Answer (score 5):

This looks fine to me. Added `above left` and `above right`, and removed the unnecessary `\left...\right` construction

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=tiny]
&\mathbb{S}ig^I
\arrow[dl,phantom , shift left]
\arrow[dl, "(Mod^{I})^{op}" above left] 
\arrow[dr, "Sen^{I}",above right] &\\
\mathbb{C}at^{op}&\models &\mathbb{S}et
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With some more tricks: using math italic that way leads to not so good output. I would never use blackboard bold for the first letter, but with a personal command it's easy
to change the typesetting in the *whole* document by modifying just the definition.

The vertical alignment of the two labels is obtained by using `\mathstrut` in the one on the right, which adds a “phantom parenthesis”.

Similarly, the arrows have approximately the same angle by adding a phantom `\op` in the lower right entry.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\newcommand\cat[1]{\makecat#1\makecat}
\def\makecat#1#2\makecat{\mathbb{#1}\mathrm{#2}}
\newcommand{\fun}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
\newcommand{\op}{^{\mathrm{op}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=0em]
& \cat{Sig}^I
  \arrow[dl, swap, "(\fun{Mod}^{I})\op"]
  \arrow[dr, "\mathstrut\fun{Sen}^{I}"]
\\
\cat{Cat}\op & \models & \cat{Set}\hphantom{\op}
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

`\cat`s have `\fun`. `;-)`

Answer (score 1):

I try with TikZ.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\a{2}
\path 
(0,0)      node (Si) {$\mathbb{S}ig^I$}
+(-135:\a) node (Ca) {$\mathbb{C}at^{op}$} 
+(-45:\a)  node (Se) {$\mathbb{S}et$}
(Si|-Ca)   node{$\models$};

\draw (Si)--(Ca) node[pos=.4,left]{$(Mod^{I})^{op}$};
\draw (Si)--(Se) node[pos=.4,right=1mm]{$Sen^{I}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```